# How can I create a multi-hierarchical 'tree'? (If it can be called a tree)

Tags: php, mysql, visualization, hierarchical-data, data-visualization

i have a list of say `courses` and `certificates` and `fun_days`. These are all called `objects`. Every object has its requirements `object_requirements`. A requirement can be either one of the `objects` or several of them.

You can take any `object` ***without*** `object_requirements` as a `starting point`. "Everybody is allowed to ***have*** those objects."

So it could be that:

- `Introduction_course` is a starting point (no requirements)
- `Introduction_certificate` can be obtained by those who have `Introduction_course` (this `course` is a requirement of this `certificate`)
- `Funday_swimming` can be obtained by those who have a `Introduction_certificate` (the certificate is a requirement of the `fun_day`).

Is there a way to create a visual representation of the hierarchical or somewhat structured-flow of this system? The example is fairly simple, but multiple requirements anywhere in the 'tree' should be possible.

This is how I store the requirements:

```
TABLE: OBJECT_REQUIREMENT
 OBJECTTYPE                (pk)
 OBJECTID                  (pk)
 REQUIREMENT_OBJECTTYPE    (pk)
 REQUIREMENT_OBJECTID      (pk)

TABLE: COURSE
 OBJECTID                  (pk)
 OBJECTTYPE                       // value is always [1] for course

TABLE: CERTIFICATE
 OBJECTID                  (pk)
 OBJECTTYPE                       // value is always [2] for certificate

TABLE: FUN_DAY
 OBJECTID                  (pk)
 OBJECTTYPE                       // value is always [3] for fun_day
```

Oh and I use PHP and MySQL. But any piece of software which could generate these visual representations would be more than welcome also!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider something like a directed graph, to which this previous SO question might be useful:

[How to do directed graph drawing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850031/how-to-do-directed-graph-drawing-in-php)

Comment: Just the thing I needed! Gonna look into GraphViz interface in PEAR

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<li>` tag, so:

- Introduction_course
  - Introduction_certificate
    - funday_swimming
  - Another certificate

If you are trying to show it in html.

If you want something that is more graphical, you can use svg files or canvas tags (in html5) in order to draw the graph, or, just use lib_gd to draw a bitmap, and make it into an imagemap, if needed.